# Filtering: Json containing array of Json objects

Tags: json, dictionary, filter, python-3.8

I have a variable `prev_data` of type `dict` which contains a value as shown

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "color_code": {
        "bg_color": "#FFD9E1", 
        "border": null, 
        "label": "#000000"
      }, 
      "description": "Description Lorem epsum....", 
      "display_text": "display_text 1", 
      "icon_url": "http://www.icon.com", 
      "key": "key_text 1", 
      "label": "label_text 1"
    }, 
    {
      "color_code": {
        "bg_color": "#D4FFFA", 
        "border": null, 
        "label": "#000000"
      }, 
      "description": "Desc Lorem epsum....", 
      "display_text": "display_text 2", 
      "icon_url": "http://www.icon.com", 
      "key": "key_text 2", 
      "label": "label_text 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to reduce the above to this

```
"values": [
  {
    "key": "key_text 1",
    "label": "label_tex 1",
    "description": "Description Lorem epsum...."
  },
  {
    "key": "key_text 2",
    "label": "label_tex 2",
    "description": "Desc Lorem epsum...."
  }
]
```

So far tried but no luck

```
* print(item.get("key") for item in prev_data["values"]) # <generator object function.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x055C3D48>
* drug_safety_advices_extra = {k: v for k, v in prev_data.items() if k.startswith("key")} # for key, label, description
```

Answer (score 1):

try this
why not create an empty dict add data and then append it to list named values. inside the loop and for final json add it into another dict.
like this,

```
import json

jobj = """{
  "values": [
    {
      "color_code": {
        "bg_color": "#FFD9E1", 
        "border": null, 
        "label": "#000000"
      }, 
      "description": "Description Lorem epsum....", 
      "display_text": "display_text 1", 
      "icon_url": "http://www.icon.com", 
      "key": "key_text 1", 
      "label": "label_text 1"
    }, 
    {
      "color_code": {
        "bg_color": "#D4FFFA", 
        "border": null, 
        "label": "#000000"
      }, 
      "description": "Desc Lorem epsum....", 
      "display_text": "display_text 2", 
      "icon_url": "http://www.icon.com", 
      "key": "key_text 2", 
      "label": "label_text 2"
    }
  ]
}"""

j = json.loads(jobj)
jarr = j['values']
values = []
for i in jarr:
    tmp = {}
    tmp['key'] = i['key']
    tmp['label'] = i['label']
    tmp['description'] = i['description']
    values.append(tmp)

final_json = {}
final_json['values'] = values
print(final_json)
```

Comment: Actually `prev_data` is of type `dict` not string, Sorry it's my bad. I will mention in question

Comment: you can try this approach using dict. replace null with None.

Comment: I can't replace it, It is dynamically loaded data

Comment: Your answer is right, But it won't work for mine situation. I found solution, Thanks for your reply